# Testing Chrome In App Payments

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, android-pay, chrome-web-store

I am looking to integerate IAP (https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) in to my extenstion but I can't seem to find a way to test payments.

If I switch the env to `sandbox` I get and error of type `"ENV_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERROR"`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Purchasing it using my tester account charges my credit card. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope I just issue my self a refund and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the docs you link:

> ### Testing purchases
>
> Prior to publishing your app to the world, you can test the In-App Payment experience by publishing it only to trusted testers. When your app is published to trusted testers, the purchase flow will proceed normally, except they will not be charged.

Comment: This is not true, it still charges you, I see it on my credit card transactions.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's Visibility option is set to Private?

Comment: Yes definitely set to private, my google wallet account is in the testers list. But I still get a charge on my card.

Comment: I had the same problem too. Any resolution on this? I even tried to set my price to Rs. 1, but it doesn't let me.

Comment: Over six months later and I have the same problem.  Set my chrome extension to "publishing it only to trusted testers" and added their email addresses to the testers and it still charged the credit cards. Does Google not care that they are not telling the truth about this?

Comment: @Jeff ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯ I'm only quoting the docs. You may want to [contact CWS support](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/) regarding this.